# Invoking Applet Methods - Firefox 12 bug

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, applet, deployjava

I have one problem  with Firefox 12 (newer Firefox works well, and another browsers works well too).

In Firefox 12 **MyApplet** is undefined.

In another browsers **everything works well**.

In newer Firefox  **everything works well too.**

but I need to fix this **in firefox 12 too.**

```
....
....
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callbackFunction() {
        ....
        MyApplet.getData(); 
            // My applet is undefined in firefox 12.
        ....
}

</script>
</head>
<body >   
     <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
     <script >  
     var javaVersion='1.6';
            var startApplet = function(){     
                    var attributes = {
                            id: 'MyApplet', scriptable: 'true',
                            code:'X.Y.Z.MyApplet.class',
                            archive:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/applets/MyApplet.jar'
                        };
                        var parameters = {
                            challenge : "${serverChallenge}",
                            callbackFunction : 'callbackFunction()',
                            language: "${pageContext.response.locale.language}"
                        };
                        var version = '1.6';
                        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
                       }         
                    startApplet();
      </script>



</body>
</html>
```

is it possible, to solve that problem using JS or something like that?

Comment: FF 12 - seriously?  My current FF is showing version 20.0.1.  Just what vintage is FF 12?  BTW - I've seen a lot of applet problems, but I've never seen one where either an applet or JS could actually **solve** the problem.  The best you can hope for is that they can identify when the problem occurs and advise the user.

Comment: Yeap, seriously. Its very big project. so some people might have Firefox 12 too. It should be better if I manage to solve that problem using JS or applet.

Comment: Good luck with that..

Comment: is there any chance to solve that problem? what do you think?

Comment: *"what do you think?"*  Did you miss the last 2 sentences of my 1st comment?  Did I accidentally write them in Swahili?

Comment: thank you my friend. I know that you are right-  My and your opinions are the same too. but I write this question for another people too, It's interesting if some of them have another opinions. I know that its impossible to solve this problem using JS. But might be someone have another answer. thank you again. :-)

Comment: try to update your FF from 12.0 to currently accessible version (see help->about->Update) after that try run the applet again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's solution: updating Firefox;